# Cannot Find Device IP on Motorola NVG510 Device List

Tags: port-forwarding, ipv4

I'm attempting to port-forward through my Motorola NVG510 and I know I can port-forward but the router isn't finding my device in the Device List so I cannot connect the port to my device. The Motorola NVG510 has a Device List that shows the IPV4 Addresses of all of the devices connected to the network and their respective names if they have one. I can see a computer that belongs to a family member and an iPad that belongs to a family member and many other addresses, but the device I want to forward does not show up, as I know the IPV4 address of my device and it is not shown, even when I scan for devices and restart the router. Is there a way to add my device to the Device List or somehow make my device shown?

I know this device is connected to the router because I'm on the internet and this is the only router/internet connection in range of my computer, and my computer says that it's connected to said router.

I'm relatively new to networking and stuff so I don't know all of the terminology nor how to do a lot of stuff, I'm trying to learn so go easy.

If this isn't the best place to ask this question or something please redirect me to where I can get the answer, thanks. And if you need more info I'll be more than welcome to give as much as I can.

Comment: I tried again and I managed to get my IPV4 on the Device List so I went to complete the port-forward and everything was loading extremely slow, so my impatient self restarted the router and my IPV4 disappeared from the list and I have not been able to get the IPV4 back on the list and I have no indication of how either.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are attempting to forward a port to a Windows Computer (not stated)...

[Give your computer a static IP address](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/) outside of the DHCP range (you should be able to find the DHCP range in your routers settings. 
e.g. if your gateway is 192.168.1.1 and the DHCP pool is 192.168.1.2-100
set your static IP to 192.168.1.101

Then set the port forward to that static IP address instead of using a device list.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar experience while trying to portfoward a raspberry pi.  The device list wouldn't show the raspberry pi was connected even though it was using an ethernet cable with no wifi capability and internet access was proven.  `ifconfig` on the raspberry pi displayed 192.168.1.239 while the device list wouldn't even show that ip as being off.

My solution was to restart the device from `http://192.168.1.254/cgi-bin/restart.ha`.  Afterwards the device was still not listed until unplugging the ethernet cable, keeping it unplugged for at least a minute and plugging it back in.  After pressing **Scan for Devices** the device name was still blank but that IPv4 was listed and status was on.

Before this I had tried Clearing Device List, physically unplugging the router/modem's power, connecting the ethernet cable to different ports of the router/modem all with no success.